# How to include .htaccess in tar commands?

Tags: unix

Whenever I do

```
tar -pczf file.tar.gz *
```

it ignores any `.htaccess` files, and I can't see in the man how to include it.

Comment: there is worse.. if you have some directories with dotted files, and you want to backup all of them, it will NOT backup the dotted files in subdirectories either..

[root@jedi ~]# mkdir a
[root@jedi ~]# mkdir a/.a
[root@jedi ~]# touch a/ooo
[root@jedi ~]# touch a/.a/ooo22
[root@jedi ~]# 
[root@jedi ~]# tar cvf ahaha  a/*
a/ooo

[root@jedi ~]# tar cvf ahaha  a/
a/
a/ooo
a/.a/
a/.a/ooo22

Answer (score 113):

The shell is expanding `*` to all files in the current directory that do *not* start with a dot. This is the same rule that `ls` uses by default (by convention, files whose names start with a dot are considered "hidden" in Unix). Try instead:

```
tar -pczf file.tar.gz .
```

Using `.` at the end will collect *all* files in the current directory, including those whose names start with a dot.

Comment: You *could* also glob with * .* as in: "tar -pczf file.tar.gz * .*"

Comment: Note that `.` adds an uppermost level folder named `.` to the tar file.

Comment: I guess the trick is using . instead of *.

Comment: I just tried `* .*` intuitively, and got all files starting with a `.` *twice* in the created archive. The solution provided in this answer did help however.

Answer (score 35):

The problem isn't `tar`; the shell does not include hidden files in `*`. Do

```
tar -pczf file.tar.gz * .htaccess
```

And next time, perhaps this question could be posted on SuperUser.

Answer (score 8):

if your task allows you to hop up one directory level and tar the whole directory it works just fine and you don't have to remember anything special to make it work (I almost always forget the other way, and end up with tgz's missing .htaccess files)

```
tar -pczfv httpdocs.tar.gz httpdocs
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can, why not use:

```
tar -pczf file.tar.gz `find .`
```

Comment: this will include `.` directory. which is not different to `tar -pczf file.tar.gz .` and very different from `tar -pczf file.tar.gz *` which put everything at tar root.

Comment: `tar -pczf file.tar.gz \`ls -A\`  ` will omit the `.` and `..` directories while neatly including all hidden files